# Duvida sobre insert em banco com chave estrangeira usando linq

Tags: c#, linq, sql-select

Estou com uma duvida, como inserir dados em uma tabela Mysql, usando linq, tenho as tabelas abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou usando o método abaixo para inserir:

```
public void inserirCarteira(float cpf, string codigo, double valor, int quant, double vtotal)
    {
        try
        {

            validarInserir(cpf, codigo, valor, quant, vtotal);
            // instancia  o banco de dados
            bancotccEntities1 bco = new bancotccEntities1();
            bco.Database.Connection.Open();
            // cria um objeto 
            carteira cart = new carteira();
            // popula o objeto
            cart.cpf = cpf;
            cart.codigo = codigo;
            cart.valoracao = valor;
            cart.qtdacao = quant;
            cart.vtotalacao = vtotal;

            // adciona um objeto ao banco
            bco.AddTocarteira(cart);
            //salva o objeto no banco
            bco.SaveChanges();
            bco.Database.Connection.Close(); 
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {

            throw new Exception(e1.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Sei que tenho que usar a minha chave estrangeira mas não sei como seria algo como: *cart.carteira_idcarteira* ?

Se for como vou inserir valores já que o *idusuario* é chave primária da tabela usuário e é auto incremente, então não sei qual será o valor deste campo no momento de fazer uma inserção.

Alguém pode me dar uma idéia de como fazer?

Comment: Não entendi. Você quer como preencher qual chave estrangeira em qual inserção? Carteira ou Usuário?

Comment: Primeiro sugiro você padronizar os nomes da tabela, decida algum padrão pode ser separador por underscore ou maiúsculo do tp v_investido ou vInvestido, segundo Não precisa escrever idusuario, se já está na tabela usuário é evidente que o id seria referente ao usuário. Classe é melhor começar com letra maiúscula, não seria carteira e sim Carteira.

Comment: ok Obrigado! vou anotar.

Comment: Oi Cigano a minha ideia era inserir dados na tabela Carteira.

Answer (score 1):

O problema esta que você colocou Carteira como dependente de Usuario e Usuario dependente de Carteira ou seja você só pode inserir uma Carteira se houver um Usuario vinculado a ela e um Usuario se houver uma Carteira.

Tente preencher a chave e/ou objeto de relacionamento  entre os tipos antes de executa o SaveChanges()

Essa seu mapeamento esta meio confuso, você tem o Objeto Carteira e usuario com os atributos CPF e IdCarteira, quais são os atributos de relacionamento?

O Usuario pode ter 1 e somente 1 Carteira?
O Usuario pode ter 0 ou N Carteiras ?
O usuario pode ter 1 ou N Carteiras ?

Você precisa definir esses pontos antes de criar os objetos.